# é possivel utilizar JpaRepository sem entidade?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-jpa

é possivel utilizar JpaRepository sem entidade? No caso, substituindo por um DTO.

como segue o exemplo

```
@Repository
public interface BffRepository extends JpaRepository<BffDTO, String> {

@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "select\n"
        + "ent.name as enterprise_name, dep.name as department_name,\n"
        + "sq.name as squad_name, acc.firstname as job_owner_name,\n"
        + "tpt.name as test_template_name, job.name, job.job_blocked, job.job_removed,\n"
        + "job.bot_scm_branch, job.bot_scm_url, job.schedule_startdate,\n"
        + "job.expiration_date, job.timestamp,job.uuid,job.schedule_starttime,\n"
        + "tpt.job_execution_timeout\n"
        + "from portal.jobs job\n"
        + "left join portal.enterprises ent on (ent.uuid = job.enterprise_id)\n"
        + "left join portal.departments dep on (dep.uuid = job.department_id)\n"
        + "left join portal.squads sq on (sq.uuid = job.squad_id)\n"
        + "left join portal.accounts acc on (acc.uuid = job.job_owner)\n"
        + "left join portal.test_plan_templates tpt on (tpt.uuid = job.template_id) where\n"
        + "job.job_owner = ?1 and job.job_removed = false order by timestamp desc;")
List<BffDTO>buscarPorJobOwner(String jobOwner);
```

Há alternativas para este caso?

OBS: o DTO ja esta mapeado, mas não gostaria de criar uma view para transformar esse DTO em uma Entity.

Comment: você cria a query na JPA da sua entidade retornando a DTO que você deseja. Além disso você pode usar JPQL ao invés de nativeQuery, o que vai deixar sua query muito mais limpa e mais fácil de ler

Comment: Você quer uma consulta isolada sem entidade associada? Então pode ser injetar o bean de EntityManager e criá-la.

Answer (score 1):

O Jpa basicamente necessita da entidade e de suas anotações como @Entity e @Id para realizar procedimentos referentes ao banco de dados, sem isso é impossível utilizar JpaRepository, caso não queria utilizar entidade, talvez encontre uma solução melhor utilizando jpql.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).